# Get value from URL even if no parameter name is specified

Tags: jquery, url

My site currently uses `getUrlVars()` to locate the ID of a div that is to be show. If no ID is specified, the user is notified and directed back to a search page to locate the ID they want.

Here's what that code looks like.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var currentDiv = getUrlVars()["id"]; 
    $("article[data*=" + currentDiv +"]").removeClass("hidden-by-url");
    //Show link to search page if no ID is specific by URL
    if($('article.hidden-by-url').length === $('article').length){
      Swal.fire({
          html: 'html here',
          confirmButtonText: 'Find It',
          confirmButtonColor: '#00A98F'
        }).then((result) => {
          if (result.value) {
            var url = "index.php";
            $(location).attr('href',url);
          }
        })
        ;
    }
    else{
      //nothin
    };
});
```

and the user may enter the path as `www.mydomain.com/show.php?id=xyx` which would then display the `<div id="xyz"> divy stuff </div>`.

I want to account for user error: if they only type `www.mydomain.com/show.php?xyx`without `"id="`, how might I redirect or reconstruct  the url to still show the correct ID using the `getUrlVars()` method?

Or would there be a better method to accomplish this not using `getUrlVars()`?

Comment: How often does this happen?  It seems likely you are possibly putting in effort for a contrived issue that may or may not happen frequently.

Comment: Looks like you are using PHP? Why not do the query var logic in the php code using `$_GET` and just output the content you want based on the determination server side? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo, I honestly hadn't even considered doing that! Great point. I'll check into it and see if I can find a solution that way.